# IronPython launch subprocess without a console window

Tags: subprocess, ironpython

I have an app that uses an old IronPython version which does not include the [subprocess](https://ironpython-test.readthedocs.org/en/latest/library/subprocess.html) module. With that being said, I'm trying to spawn a process using:

```
from System.Diagnostics import Process
Process.Start('something.exe', 'args')
```

as seen [here](http://www.ironpython.info/index.php?title=Launching_Sub-Processes).
However, I'm not able to hide the console window that pops out when launching this new process. Any idea about how can I bypass that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from System.Diagnostics import Process
p = Process()
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = True
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute  = False
p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = True
```

Comment: Then what will be the next line ? Process.Start or p.start ?

Comment: Also, I am having trouble with my firewall security level due to EUP,  but even following the above did not help me